# Why is accessing session through HttpContext.Current bad [practice]?

Tags: session-variables, signalr, signalr-hub

I am trying out `signalR` and followed their Chat sample with a few modifications. So, in the `ChatHub.cs`, I tried to access the user's session variable and found out that I couldn't. So I've searched the web for answers and found this: [Access to Session from a Hub](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/67)

So as commented by Mr. David Fowl, accessing session variables through `HttpContext.Current` is bad. Is it really that bad that I should avoid using it? I really need to access the session variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing the reason it is bad is because your code will not work if hosted outside of the asp.net context. Since HttpContext.Current is web specific

Comment: Oh I see. I've also read that it would not be useful in webservices. Thanks! But it is okay to use it right? I don't think I'd need to use it outside asp.net context. Sorry I can't vote this up. I don't have enough reputation. I could only give you my gratitude. Thanks.